# How to prevent changes to links or elements?

Tags: javascript, element, onchange, restriction, jointjs

I need to restrict the user interaction of certain links and elements.
For example, if the user moves or deletes the item, the last state of this item will show up immediately and the graph will seem unaltered.

Ideally I am looking for a simple property that can be added when the element is created which prevents all changes to happen, e.g. `isModifiable: false`.

Since I couldn't find one, I used the `change` event and a not very elegant recursive solution for links (added as an answer below, **now *edited* with an alternative and better solution**).

Is there an ideal method for stopping or restricting changes to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Individual `Element`/`Link` restriction

I managed to solve this problem partially by modifying the events associated to the cells, e.g. for `joint.dia.Link`:

1. Add a custom function to the `change` event;
2. Once a change is triggered, remove the newly changed link from the graph;
3. Use an intact clone of the initial link and clone it again for using it as the newly restored link;
4. Add the same function to the cloned link `change` event;
5. Add the cloned link to the graph.

So these would be:

```
let mylink = new joint.dia.Link({
  source: sourceObj,
  target: targetObj,
  attrs : attrsObj
});
let mylinkClone = mylink.clone();

function restoreLink(link, changeStats) {
  link.remove();
  let rlink = mylinkClone.clone();
  rlink.on('change', restoreLink);
  rlink.addTo(graph);
}

mylink.on('change', restoreLink);
```

Once the user clicks the delete button, or tries to drag the link out, or anything else, there is literally no visual change.

This may not be a very elegant or high performance solution (due to repeated cloning) and I noticed during the period in which a [token is sent through the link](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.LinkView.prototype.sendToken), the user is still able to delete it. But if you have very specific links/elements once they are created that you need to restrict, it's still effective.

## Paper `interactive` property restrictions

This is an alternative better way to restrict specific actions on all elements or links on the paper by using [`joint.Paper.prototype.options.interactive`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.options.interactive), as [suggested by Roman in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193286/6225838).

### Restrict `Link`s

So when the paper is instantiated, if you want all the interactions with links to be permanently restricted, you can just do:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  interactive: {
    useLinkTools: false,
    labelMove: false,
    vertexRemove: false,
    vertexAdd: false
    vertexMove: false,
    arrowheadMove: false,
  },
  gridSize: 10,
  drawGrid: true,
  model: graph,
  defaultLink: new joint.shapes.app.Link,
  // other properties ....
})
```

### Restrict `Element`s

If you want to *only* restrict all elements' interactions, then:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  interactive: {
    elementMove: false,
    addLinkFromMagnet: false,
  },
  // other properties ....
})
```

### Providing a function to `interactive` (high customisation)

Or, if you **use a function for the `interactive` property** value, you just 
need to distinguish elements from links and then operate on them. For restricting *only links* interactions you just need to return `false` when these are detected:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  interactive: function (cellView) {
    if(cellView.model instanceof joint.dia.Link) {
      console.log('Link interaction');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      console.log('Element interaction of type:', cellView.model.get('type'));
      return true;
    }
  },
  // other properties ....
})
```

My preferred method of restriction for my specific case was simply done by **identifying the links connected to certain sources** and returning `false` for them:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  interactive: function (cellView) {
    if(cellView.model instanceof joint.dia.Link) {
      console.log('Link interaction');
      var lSource = cellView.model.getSourceElement();
      if(lSource instanceof joint.shapes.app.AwesomeShape){
        // do not allow links connected to these sources to be modified
        console.log(`Links with ${lSource.get('type')} sources cannot be modified!`);
        return false;
      }
      // allow other links to be modified
      return true;
    }
    console.log('Element interaction of type:', cellView.model.get('type'));
    return true;
  },
  // other properties ....
})
```

Comment: For restricting only certain events on the element/link through the function method, here's a [vertex adding restriction example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33330789/6225838) where they only need to return `{ vertexAdd: false }`.

Answer (score 2):

You should prevent a user from doing action in the paper, not prevent the programmer from doing changes to the graph.

Please see the `interactive` [option](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.options.interactive) for `dia.Paper`.

```
// add the specific attribute to your desired shape
link.set('isModifiable', true);

// use the `interactive` option within your paper
new joint.dia.Paper({
  interactive: function(cellView) {
    return cellView.model.get('isModifiable');   
  }
});
```

Note that this way you will still be able to programmatically change the link.

```
// this will trigger `change` event, but it won't be reverted
link.attr('.connection/stroke', 'red');
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, that was really helpful. However, the programmer is never restricted from modifying the event (I was doing `link.off('change')` when I needed to change them). `isModifiable` was a property I imagined it could exist (currently it does not). The `interactive` restrictions are applied to all cells in the paper, but when I used a function instead, I just needed to distinguish links from elements and identify the specific links I wanted to "freeze". I added to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48173614/6225838) a tested solution based on your feedback. It works perfectly!